# Disable password authentication for SSHwhen using Key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I’m trying to create a practice pentest box and not sure of the configuration needed to achieve one part of it.

Let’s say I get a copy of the users private key (`id_rsa`).

If I try and ssh in with the key, I am asked for a password. However if I turn password authentication off in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, it says `permission denied (public key)`.

I am trying to set the config to use the “stolen” users private key to ssh in without password.

The error seems to think I’m using my own private key without having my pub key in authorized_keys, but I am trying to use the users own private key

Comment: Please show your configurations. What command are you using? Where is the "stolen" public key? (Location and if it on client or server?) Where is the corresponding victim's public key on the server?

Comment: So the attacker can read a file which has a copy of the victims id_rsa. Also the victim has their id_rsa in the /home/user/.ssh directory. So if the attacker somehow gets a copy of their private key, they should be able to ssh user@ip -i id_rsa. The thing I’m looking for is the same as pwned 1 on vulnhub. But I checked the config and still can’t figure it out.

Comment: @Levi [edit] your question to show the configs and the commands you actually run. Use code block formatting for the files, it makes them far easier to read (the `{}` looking symbol in the edit toolbar)